# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSString *' from 'NSInteger' (aka 'int');

Tags: objective-c

Had this semantic issue while showing the xml parsed data in the table cell view. application runs successfully but when i select any row then app goes in detail view at that time app crashes. Pls help!!!

Semantic issue occurs in the **third case** in this line

```
cell.textLabel.text = aBook.bookID;
```

App Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = 
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
      cell.textLabel.text = aBook.name;
      break;
    case 1:
      cell.textLabel.text = aBook.author;
      break;
    case 2:
      cell.textLabel.text = aBook.price;
      break;
    case 3:            
      cell.textLabel.text = aBook.bookID;
      break;
  }

  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your **aBook.bookID** variable is a NSInteger, to convert it in a NSString use this:

```
case 3:            
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", aBook.bookID];
    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your case 3 would be depending upon your bookID

For int

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aBook.bookID];
```

For NSInteger

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",aBook.bookID];
```

Because You are providing int value to a string